# CouchDB replication - Unauthorized to access or create database

Tags: authentication, couchdb, replication

I am trying to setup a CouchDB database replication but both is not working via Futon and cURL/CLI: It ends up with the following error message in both cases:

**{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"unauthorized to access or create database table1"}**

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/_replicate -d '{"source": "table1",
"user_ctx": {"name": "", "roles": ["admin"]}, "target":   
"http://username:password@server:5984/table1", "create_target": false, 
"continuous": true}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

The target database is secured via a username and password and for HTTP basic authentication i added the credentials as you can see. The same error appears when i create a replication document via Futon.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can anyone help here to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

It is a little bit late but I think you need it.

(CouchDb 1.6.1)

https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication

POST /_replicate HTTP/1.1

```
{ 
    "source": {
        "url":"https://example.net:5984/table1",
        "headers":{
            "Authorization":"Basic Ym9iQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tOnBhc3N3b3Jk"
        }
    }, 
    "target":"target1", 
    "create_target": false, 
    "continuous": true
}
```

where the base64 string following the word "Basic" is the output of:

- echo -n 'username:password' | base64  (username and password for database table1 in `https://example.net:5984`.
- Very important : when you send your request you send it to an url. The target should also be the name of the database where you will replicated     "target":"`http://server:5984/table1`" -->> table1
- The request header you use to send this replication should contains the Basic token too. (a admin username and password or the superadmin password of  the target database)

### Resume

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/_replicate 
-d '{ 
    "source": {
        "url":"https://example.net:5984/table1",
        "headers":{
            "Authorization":"Basic Ym9iQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tOnBhc3N3b3Jk"
        }
    }, 
    "target":"target1", 
    "create_target": false, 
    "continuous": true
}' -H "Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWUyOnBhc3N3b3JkMg==;Content-Type: application/json"
```

- dXNlcm5hbWUyOnBhc3N3b3JkMg== : username2:password2 (base64)
- Ym9iQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tOnBhc3N3b3Jk : username:password (base64)
- username2:password2 : admin name and password of the database target1 (on `http://server:5984`)
- username:password : admin name and password of the database target1 (on `127.0.0.1:5984`)

Comment: This answer solved an issue I have had for years POST -ing to _replicator where I did not realise I was getting an 'unauthorised' response. Upon using "headers":{"Authorisation":"Basic dfdfg..."} couch executes the replication correctly. Normal username:password was NOT accepted by Couch. Well done.